# creating "Per Day" rows, from selective "Per Month" figures using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a set of sales report, containing stores that report either "per day" or "per month" sales figures.
When I plot them on the same graph, "per month" figures look like spikes, making the graph hard to comprehend.

I wish to convert those "once per month" figures, to spread out evenly over the days in a month, so that I can plot a daily sales graph.

I managed to use tidyverse, lubridate to calculate "sales_per_day" column in the data sets. How can I create rows that are "1 row per day", ie. for 2019-01, create 30 daily rows from each 1 row of monthly data?

```
sales <- tibble(
  distributor = c("StoreA", "StoreA", "StoreA", "StoreA", "StoreB"), 
  sales = c(100,200,300,400,5000), 
  date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-30"),
  freq = c("daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "monthly"))

> sales
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  distributor sales date       freq   
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      <chr>  
1 StoreA        100 2019-01-01 daily  
2 StoreA        200 2019-01-02 daily  
3 StoreA        300 2019-01-03 daily  
4 StoreA        400 2019-01-04 daily  
5 StoreB       5000 2019-01-30 monthly


wanted_sales <- tibble(
  distributor = c("StoreA", "StoreA", "StoreA", "StoreA", "StoreB", "StoreB", "StoreB", "StoreB"), 
  sales = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 5000 / 30, 5000 / 30, 5000 / 30, 5000 / 30), 
  date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04"),
  freq = c("daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily" ))

> wanted_sales
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  distributor sales date       freq 
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      <chr>
1 StoreA       100  2019-01-01 daily
2 StoreA       200  2019-01-02 daily
3 StoreA       300  2019-01-03 daily
4 StoreA       400  2019-01-04 daily
5 StoreB       167. 2019-01-01 daily
6 StoreB       167. 2019-01-02 daily
7 StoreB       167. 2019-01-03 daily
8 StoreB       167. 2019-01-04 daily

per_day <- sales %>% filter(freq == "monthly") %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(mdays = as.integer(days_in_month(as_date(date)))) %>%
  mutate(sales_per_day = sales / mdays)

> per_day
# A tibble: 1 x 6
# Groups:   date [1]
  distributor sales date       freq    mdays sales_per_day
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   <int>         <dbl>
1 StoreB       5000 2019-01-30 monthly    31          161.
```

I wish to make the resulting per_day tibble, with 30 rows, with $date column being a sequence of "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02"... "2019-01-30".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can change the `date` to actual Date class and create a new column `startdate` which would have first day of that particular month if `freq` is not `"daily"` and `sales` is divided by 30. For each `date` we use `complete` to create sequence of dates and change `freq` to `"daily"` for all.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

sales %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), 
         startdate = if_else(freq == "daily", date, floor_date(date, "month")), 
         sales = if_else(freq == "daily", sales, sales/30)) %>%
   group_by(date) %>%
   complete(date = seq(startdate, date, "1 day"), sales = sales, 
            freq = "daily", distributor = distributor) %>%
   select(-startdate)

# Groups:   date [30]
#   date       sales freq  distributor
#   <date>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>      
# 1 2019-01-01  100  daily StoreA     
# 2 2019-01-02  200  daily StoreA     
# 3 2019-01-03  300  daily StoreA     
# 4 2019-01-04  400  daily StoreA     
# 5 2019-01-01  167. daily StoreB     
# 6 2019-01-02  167. daily StoreB     
# 7 2019-01-03  167. daily StoreB     
# 8 2019-01-04  167. daily StoreB     
# 9 2019-01-05  167. daily StoreB     
#10 2019-01-06  167. daily StoreB     
# … with 25 more rows
```

Comment: Wonderful!!! Never knew complete(), what a clever function! 

In my desperate attempt I was doing it like this : 

```R
month_days <- tibble(date = as_date(paste0(as_date("2010-01-01") + 1:as.integer(as_date(now()) - as_date("2010-01-01"))))) %>%
  mutate(ymon = floor_date(date, unit = "month"))
```

This creates a tibble with list of dates, with year_mon value that I could then left_join with.

It did work, but your solution is so much better!
Thank you for showing me a brilliantly elegant way, Ronak!!