# R - Split an intervals into multiple intervals over many rows

Tags: r

The below code generates a mock dataset:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)

example_data = tibble(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3),
  Gender = c("Male", "Female", "Female"),
  Age = c(18, 28, 38),
  Time_Period = c(
    interval(as.Date(now()), as.Date(now() + months(3) + days(10))),
    interval(as.Date(now() + months(1)), as.Date(now() + months(4) + days(13))),
    interval(as.Date(now() + months(2)), as.Date(now() + months(8) + days(4)))
  )
)
```

with the following output

```
     ID Gender   Age Time_Period                   
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <Interval>                    
1     1 Male      18 2022-11-10 UTC--2023-02-20 UTC
2     2 Female    28 2022-12-10 UTC--2023-03-23 UTC
3     3 Female    38 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-07-14 UTC
```

The `Time_Period` variable for each `ID` covers a certain number of months.

For example, row one contains an interval of 3 months and 10 days. For `ID = 1` I would like a new dataset to contain four rows with a new interval column that is one month in length, and the last dataset goes until the end point of the original interval.

This would be repeated for all ID's.

The dataset would look something like the following where the next rows interval start date begins one month after the previous rows start date (spaces inserted for readability):

```
    ID Gender   Age Split_Up_Intervals                   
 <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <Interval>                    
     1 Male      18 2022-11-10 UTC--2022-12-09 UTC
     1 Male      18 2022-12-10 UTC--2023-01-09 UTC
     1 Male      18 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-02-09 UTC
     1 Male      18 2023-02-10 UTC--2023-02-20 UTC

     2 Female    28 2022-12-10 UTC--2023-01-09 UTC
     2 Female    28 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-02-09 UTC
     2 Female    28 2023-02-10 UTC--2023-03-09 UTC
     2 Female    28 2023-03-10 UTC--2023-03-23 UTC

     3 Female    38 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-02-09 UTC
     3 Female    38 2023-02-10 UTC--2023-03-09 UTC
     3 Female    38 2023-03-10 UTC--2023-04-09 UTC
     3 Female    38 2023-04-10 UTC--2023-05-09 UTC
     3 Female    38 2023-05-10 UTC--2023-06-09 UTC
     3 Female    38 2023-06-10 UTC--2023-07-09 UTC
     3 Female    38 2023-07-10 UTC--2023-07-14 UTC
```

I think this can be done using something similar to here ([creating "Per Day" rows, from selective "Per Month" figures using tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770224/creating-per-day-rows-from-selective-per-month-figures-using-tidyverse)) but I can't quite get it to work. Also, the actual dataset I'll be working with has a large number of columns so I'd like all of the other variables to be duplicated in each new row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that goes some way to doing what you want. The idea is that for each interval we need to create a column containing a sequence defined by the interval (i.e. if the interval covers 4.5 months, there is a sequence of five monthly intervals).

```
ex2=data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3), x = c('a','b','c'), n=c(5,6,3))
```

Now for any particular row, we can use `merge` to append a column containing a variable-length sequence, and let's use the value in the `n` column to define the length of the sequence:

```
merge(ex2[1,], 
      data.frame(s=seq(1,ex2[1,]$n)))
```

```
  Id x n s
1  1 a 5 1
2  1 a 5 2
3  1 a 5 3
4  1 a 5 4
5  1 a 5 5
```

Now, somehow `apply` this to each row of the data frame and bind the output data frames. I worked out you can do this by [converting each row of the data frame into a list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-r-dataframe-rows-to-a-list/) and then using `lapply`:

```
res=lapply(split(ex2,seq(nrow(ex2))), 
           FUN=function(x) merge(x, data.frame(s=seq(x$n))))
```

```
$`1`
  Id x n s
1  1 a 5 1
2  1 a 5 2
3  1 a 5 3
4  1 a 5 4
5  1 a 5 5

$`2`
  Id x n s
1  2 b 6 1
2  2 b 6 2
3  2 b 6 3
4  2 b 6 4
5  2 b 6 5
6  2 b 6 6

$`3`
  Id x n s
1  3 c 3 1
2  3 c 3 2
3  3 c 3 3
```

Now use `dplyr::bind_rows` and `do.call` to combine the data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
do.call('bind_rows', res)
```

We can apply the same idea to your example data. Instead of using `n` to define the length of the sequence we create a sequence starting at the start of the interval, a step size of one month, and whose length is the number of months (or part thereof) in the interval:

```
do.call("bind_rows", 
        lapply(split(example_data,seq(nrow(example_data))), 
               FUN=function(x) merge(x,  
                      data.frame(start_date=seq(from=int_start(x$Time_Period),
                                                by=duration(1, 'months'),
                                                length.out=ceiling(x$Time_Period/duration(1, 'months')))))))
```

```
   ID Gender Age                Time_Period          start_date
1   1   Male  18 2022-11-10 UTC--2023-02-20      UTC 2022-11-10 00:00:00
2   1   Male  18 2022-11-10 UTC--2023-02-20      UTC 2022-12-10 10:30:00
3   1   Male  18 2022-11-10 UTC--2023-02-20      UTC 2023-01-09 21:00:00
4   1   Male  18 2022-11-10 UTC--2023-02-20      UTC 2023-02-09 07:30:00
5   2 Female  28 2022-12-10 UTC--2023-03-23      UTC 2022-12-10 00:00:00
6   2 Female  28 2022-12-10 UTC--2023-03-23      UTC 2023-01-09 10:30:00
7   2 Female  28 2022-12-10 UTC--2023-03-23      UTC 2023-02-08 21:00:00
8   2 Female  28 2022-12-10 UTC--2023-03-23      UTC 2023-03-11 07:30:00
9   3 Female  38 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-07-14      UTC 2023-01-10 00:00:00
10  3 Female  38 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-07-14      UTC 2023-02-09 10:30:00
11  3 Female  38 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-07-14      UTC 2023-03-11 21:00:00
12  3 Female  38 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-07-14      UTC 2023-04-11 07:30:00
13  3 Female  38 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-07-14      UTC 2023-05-11 18:00:00
14  3 Female  38 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-07-14      UTC 2023-06-11 04:30:00
15  3 Female  38 2023-01-10 UTC--2023-07-14      UTC 2023-07-11 15:00:00
```

I don't know enough about lubridate to continue here (there looks to be a problem with the start dates not being exactly one month, you need to set up the end dates properly, and also create an interval) but hopefully that helps.